# How to remove parameters in URL .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very big problem, I'am using to CLEAN URL this [link](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/).We are make a small CMS system for PHP and make a new web site.

Problem is, my customer.

My customer don't want these link style :

```
www.example.com/page/about-us
www.example.com/page/contact-us
www.example.com/anotherpage/lorem-ipsum-dolar
```

How to remove or hide /page, /anotherpage using .htaccess ?

My .htaccess file is ;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Since your `.htaccess` doesn't do *any* real rewriting, you can't fix it there. All incoming paths are offloaded to your application logic, so adapt your front controller to whatever your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use .htaccess Rewrite rule to solve this issue:

```
RewriteRule url-wanted$ actual-url [L,QSA]
```

Example:

```
RewriteRule www.example.com/about-us$ www.example.com/page/about-us [L,QSA]
```